# Implementing the bootstrap-tokenfield (jquery widget) in polymer

Tags: jquery, polymer

I think this is more of a jquery integration issue, but here is my problem / bug.  I'm trying to wrap up the [bootstrap-tokenfield][1] as a polymer element but getting the following error / trace:

```
Error: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
  at GeneratedWrapper.mixin.insertBefore (http://localhost:3005/ShadowDOM/src/wrappers/Node.js:266:30)
  at Object.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js:6067:21)
  at jQuery.fn.extend.domManip (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js:6262:15)
  at jQuery.fn.extend.before (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js:6065:15)
  at Tokenfield.createToken (http://localhost:3005/elements/ui-widgets/bootstrap-tokenfield/bootstrap-tokenfield.js:175:21)
```

The code:

```
<polymer-element name="my-bootstrap-tokenfield">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-tokenfield.css">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="red,green,blue" />
  </template>
  <script src="bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-bootstrap-tokenfield', {
      applyAuthorStyles : true, 
      ready : function() {
        // default example
        $(this.$.tokenfield).tokenfield({
           typeahead: {
               name: 'tags',
               local: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
           },
           allowDuplicates: true
        });
      }
    })
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Thoughts, suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure `<script src="bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>` will work. Have you tried moving it outside the polymer-element? There are known issues with using Bootstrap's JS widgets inside of Polymer. This is mainly because it does not understand Shadow DOM. Looks to be the your case from that error.

Comment: BTW, the stackoverflow convention is to post the solution to your question as an answer, that way the question looks answered, and others can upvote it when it helps them etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ebidel helping me come to the fix.  Wrap the input in a 'div' tag and all is well.  Makes sense as the tokenfield the 'input' parent to build out the widget.

```
<template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-tokenfield.css">
    <div>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="red,green,blue" />
    </div>
</template>
```